# Non-server hosted pages - file:///, chrome://, and about:

Tags: react-router

Hi all I am new to react router. Things worked great on pages hosted on server. However locally it is failing badly.

I am using react-router to create a browser addon. I have three different cases, all of which are failing. I set the base path to a global constant named `BASE_PATH`.

First app is url of `about:mytool`. Plugging this into `new URL('about:mytool')` correctly shows that `host` is a blank string. So this is how I set up my router:

I want my path seperator to be `?`.

```
render((
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="about:mytool?" component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={IndexPage}/>
      <Route path="page1" component={Page1}/>
      <Route path="page2" component={Page2}/>
      <Route path="*" component={NoMatch}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.body)
```

And then my links are like this:

etc.

However doing the above causes absolutely blank to render.
My other two cases are similar. The only difference is that `about:mytool`changes to:

- `const BASE_PATH = "chrome://mytool/content/app.html"`
- and last case `const BASE_PATH = "file:///C:/Users/mytool.html"`

Can you please advise on how to get it to work on non-server hosted pages.

Is it possible to not

Comment: react-router appears to be non-functional when run on a page served via the `file://` protocol. It doesn't throw or crash, it just silently does nothing. It seems like it things there is no more work to do.

I don't know why that is, but I'm currently debugging it for my own project. If I figure it out, I'll post here.